# SQL query to return matching and non matching rows in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a single table and want to do an SQL query to return matching rows and also non matching rows in Postgres. It would be great if the SQL also worked for Informix, but this is not a requirement.

```
create temp table t1 (cust integer, product char(16), qty numeric(16,2));

insert into t1 values(1000, 11, 100);
insert into t1 values(1000, 11, 200);
insert into t1 values(1000, 22, 300);
insert into t1 values(1001, 22, 400);
insert into t1 values(1002, 33, 500);
insert into t1 values(1003, 44, 600);
insert into t1 values(1004, 55, 700);
insert into t1 values(1004, 55, 800);

select cust,
       product,
       sum(qty)
from t1
where product = '11'
group by 1,2
union all
select cust,
       null,
       null
from t1
where product != '11'
and cust not in (select cust from t1 where product = '11')
order by cust;
```

```
 cust |     product      |  sum   
------+------------------+--------
 1000 | 11               | 300.00
 1001 |                  |       
 1002 |                  |       
 1003 |                  |       
 1004 |                  |     
 1004 |                  |
```

I want all rows where cust is equal to the specified product, but I also want all cust numbers to be returned with null for product and qty that do not have the product. I have two problems. Column cust should be unique, there are two duplicate rows returned for cust 1004 and if I use distinct in the query it gives an error about data type on the qty field. The second problem is that this SQL take a very long time when run against a larger data set, like 10,000 rows.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Unrelated, but: [don't use the `char` data type](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a conditional aggregation using a `filter()` clause:

```
select t1.cust,
       max(t1.product) filter (where t1.product = '11') as product,
       sum(t1.qty) filter (where t1.product = '11')
from t1 
group by t1.cust, t1.product
order by t1.cust, t1.product
```

The `max(t1.product) ...` could also be written as `case when t1.product = '11' then t1.product else null end as product` and is only there to hide the actual product number. If you don't mind seeing the product number, then you can simply use `t1.product` there

Answer (score 0):

Ypou could try using an  aggregation filter eg:

```
select cust,  product,  sum( case when product = '11' then qty  else 0 end) sum
from t1
group by 1,2
order by cust
```